# onfocusout not working on latest lit-element version 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, lit-element, polymer-3.x

```
firstUpdated() {
  let element = this.renderRoot.getElementById('input');
      element.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
        this.inputFocus = false;
        this.requestRender();
      });
}

<dropdown-list id="list"></dropdown-list>

<button @focusout = ${e => this.renderRoot.getElementById("list").style.display = "none" }></button>
```

`onfocusout` not working in the latest version and I tried several things but it's not working.

`dropdown-list` is a component.

Comment: Can you please clarify the code a little? What is the element you're trying to add the event listener to? The `<button>`, an `<input>`? Also, what does `this.inputFocus` do?